# Why are beings born?

Tags: rebirth, birth-stories

Does anyone have an explanation as to how Buddha explains the reasons as to why are beings born? What is the reason for birth?

Comment: I don't think this is an actual answer to your question, so I will allow those with more knowledge to answer that (Buddha's commentary about birth). But for myself, I think of the answer as being similar to the answer to, "Why does a pebble skitter across the ground when kicked?" Because conditions cause it. Simply that. We are as waves in an ocean, and waves rise, peak, and fall, over and over, because that's simply what the conditions of the water cause.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why "beings(sattānaṃ)" are born, there is causal for for it.  and causal for birth (jati) is Existence (bhava).  This is from dependent  origination or Transcendental Dependent Arising (pali - Pratītyasamutpāda).

Please make sure you understand the word "being" as per Buddha.  beings or sattānaṃ is a difficult term to understand.  ("being" is not the same as permanent soul).

recommendation for further study

- [Satta Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn23/sn23.002.than.html)
- [Dependent origination](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.002.than.html)

Comment: I'm going to try to use an example to explain it, because of protons, electrons come to be; because electrons, element comes to be; because elements, molecules come to be; because molecules, mass  comes to be; because masses, gravitational force comes to be; because gravitational force, a planet comes to be........    you can see from this example (Im not a physicist so my example might be flawed but you get the idea) a planet doesnt have a reason for coming to be, it has causal.

Comment: As I understand, in the aticca-samuppada-vibhanga Sutta (Dependent origination), beings are born because of ignorance?

Comment: yes..  "... Not knowing about dukkha, not knowing about the origin of dukkha, not knowing about the cessation of dukkha, not knowing about the way leading to the cessation of dukkha — this is called ignorance.."